# Removing HTML from a converted text file

Tags: email, flow

I need help with a flow that converts the body of an email to text. The flow I've created works as follows:

1. email comes to a shared mailbox
2. an item in a Sharepoint list is created
3. the body of the email is converted to text
4. the converted text becomes an attachment to the item created

The trouble is that when I open the newly created text file, it is shown in html.

I've tried various steps in the flow to strip the html out of it or convert to pdf, but so far no success. I was hoping this could be done out of the box.

Any suggestions?

[image: part 1 of flow]
[image: part 2 of flow]

Answer (score 0):

After more testing, I figured it out by making these changes to my flow:

1. Put the value "The plain text content" into a field that exists on your SharePoint list. This is (I think) what is produced by the *HTML to Text* step. In my case it's the "Body of Email" field.
2. Then put that *same* value into the *File Content* field of the *Add attachment* step.

Making these changes produced a proper text file as the attachment and opened up in my browser as clean text. This file also had the proper line breaks, so it reads like I was hoping.
[image: answer to my post]